# Get all classes and populate Dropdown

Tags: jquery

I want to read all the classes (July, August, etc.) and write to an array. With this array I want to populate a Dropdown. So far I have the following, but the problem is that I get an array in which only the July appears. Hope some one can Help me. Thanks!

```js
var classList =$('span').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
   console.log(classList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <span class="date Juli firstChild">16.07.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date Juli firstChild">21.07.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date August firstChild">01.08.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date August firstChild">16.08.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date August firstChild">31.08.2015</span>
</div>
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mwpb9s2/6/

Comment: Can you amend the HTML at all? It would be more semantic, and simpler, to put the month names in a `data` attribute and then loop over those.

Comment: Sure. Like this? data-month="July"

Comment: Excellent - I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can amend the HTML it would be more semantic, and simpler, to put the month names in a data attribute and then loop over those to generate your array. Try this:

```js
var months = [];
$('.date').each(function() {
    var month = $(this).data('month');
    if (months.indexOf(month) == -1) 
        months.push(month);
})

// create an option in the select per month
for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    $('select').append('<option>' + months[i] + '</option>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <span class="date firstChild" data-month="Juli">16.07.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date firstChild" data-month="Juli">21.07.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date firstChild" data-month="August">01.08.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date firstChild" data-month="August">16.08.2015</span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span class="date firstChild" data-month="August">31.08.2015</span>
</div>

<select name="months"></select>
```